# CSS + Thyemleaf - CSS not reflecting on the page

Tags: spring, css, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I am having problem with CSS in my Spring boot app.

I have the following project structure.

- src/resources/static/ (for css files)
- src/resources/templates/ (for html file)

In my html page, I am using the following.

```
<link rel="stylesheet"  th:href="@{static/site.css}"  href="static/site.css" type="text/css"/>
```

This doesn't work. Am I missing something here?

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just use `th:href="@{/site.css}"`